# Using regions in a CompositeView for subview

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm using a CompositeView to create a grid of images that they had some events on it. This is how it looks like:

```
Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    events: {
        'click li.feed-thumb': 'clickElement',
    },

    template: _.template(template),

    itemView: ItemFeedView,
    itemViewContainer: "#feed ul.feed",

    clickElement: function(event) { 
        var profile = new ProfileFeedView();

    }
});
```

My template for this CompositeView contains a `<li>` element that will render the profile when I click on a image. I use the same `<li>` for all the events of click into a image. I would like to handle this as a region, because I understand that doing it as region Marionette will handle the opening and closing of the views.

I think CompositeView do not support a `regions: {profileRegion: '#feed-profile'}`, what's my options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a Layout View in which you can specify as many regions as you want, so you can create a list region in which you can put your composite view and a profile region in which you can put a item view that will render the profile.

[Marionette's docs -- Layout View](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md)

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you want to have regions in your CompositeView you can also do something like this:

```
var YourView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    regions: {
       "someRegion": ".someRegionClass"
    },
    "initialize": function(options) {
       this._initializeRegions(options);
    },
    "onDestroy": function() {
       this.regionManager.destroy();
    }
})
_.each(["_initializeRegions", "_initRegionManager",
        "_buildRegions", "addRegion", "addRegions",
        "removeRegion", "getRegion", "getRegions",
        "_reInitializeRegions", "getRegionManager"], function(prop) {
    PaginatorView.prototype[prop] = Marionette.LayoutView.prototype[prop];
});
```

To be honest, it works but i haven't tested it for full functionality.

view.someRegion.show(otherView) works.

(also works for other views i guess and you will have to add your other options needed to extend the view of course)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Manfred said I implemented it this way on a Marionette Composite View:

```
View.ListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: listTpl,
    emptyView: noItemsTpl,
    childView: View.ListItem,
    childViewContainer: '#items-list',

    regions: {
       "someRegion": "#someRegion"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        //give this composite view a LayoutView behaviour with added region manager
        this.regionManager = new Marionette.RegionManager();
        _.each(["_initializeRegions", "_initRegionManager",
                "_buildRegions", "addRegion", "addRegions",
                "removeRegion", "getRegion", "getRegions",
                "_reInitializeRegions", "getRegionManager"], function(prop) {
            Marionette.CompositeView.prototype[prop] = Marionette.LayoutView.prototype[prop];
        });
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.regions, function(value, key) {
            var region = that.addRegion(key, value);
            that[key] = region;
        });
    },

    onDestroy: function() {
       this.regionManager.destroy();
    }
});
```

This way you will be able to interact with your CompositeView instance the exact same way you do with a LayoutView instance:

```
var listView = new View.ListView({ ... });
var anotherView = new View.AnotherView({ ... });
listView.someRegion.show(anotherView);
```